# Chef Installation Error - Error executing action `run` on resource

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chef

I am trying install chef (chef-server_11.0.4-1.ubuntu.12.04) on ubuntu 12.04.5 64 bit.

After the installation, when I run "chef-server-ctl reconfigure" getting following error.

let me know how to install it.

```
[2014-12-20T14:16:10+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-12-20T14:16:10+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated
[2014-12-20T14:16:10+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-20T14:16:10+05:30] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid] (chef-server::rabbitmq line 80) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
STDOUT: Waiting for rabbit@localhost ...
pid is 6031 ...
STDERR: Error: process_not_running
---- End output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
Ran /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid returned 2
```

***Updated error after restarting Rabbitmq Server***

```
> [2014-12-23T09:55:15+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
> [2014-12-23T09:55:15+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete Chef
> Client failed. 8 resources updated [2014-12-23T09:55:15+05:30] FATAL:
> Stacktrace dumped to
> /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
> [2014-12-23T09:55:15+05:30] FATAL:
> Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[verify-system-status]
> (chef-server::bootstrap line 21) had an error:
> Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with
> [0], but received '7'
> ---- Begin output of curl -sf http://localhost:8000/_status ---- STDOUT: STDERR:
> ---- End output of curl -sf http://localhost:8000/_status ---- Ran curl -sf http://localhost:8000/_status returned 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a known issue with the chef installation on Ubuntu.  During the reconfigure it attempts to launch and connect to rabbitmq however the rabbitmq server is already running so the start fails.

The other thing that can potentially happen is not having a localhost entry in your /etc/hosts file.

The most likely thing is the already running rabbitmq, in which case give this a try:

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop && chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

If that doesn't work check to make sure the following exists in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would improve this answer

Comment: More explanation added

Comment: Updated error after restarting rabbitmq in question & hosts file contains localhost
`127.0.0.1       localhost.localadmin    localhost`
`10.9.17.106     chef.123.com            chef`

Comment: It started working after rabbitmq-services restart. thought it was not working, I just gave a try to chef-server-ctl reconfigure and it worked. I did not understand why this did not work when I did last time. strange.. :-\

Answer (score 0):

nginx is probably not started. What's the output of these:

`chef-server-ctl status
lsof -i:8000
chef-server-ctl tail`

I can't remember if Ubuntu comes with lsof or not, so you may need to install it with `apt-get install lsof -y`

Comment: `**lsof -i:8000**
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
beam.smp 979 chef_server   36u  IPv4 907617      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
---------------------------
**chef-server-ctl status**
run: bookshelf: (pid 981) 448641s; run: log: (pid 980) 448641s
run: chef-expander: (pid 983) 448641s; run: log: (pid 978) 448641s
run: chef-solr: (pid 5537) 448471s; run: log: (pid 973) 448641s
run: erchef: (pid 979) 448641s; run: log: (pid 977) 448641s
run: postgresql: (pid 984) 448641s; run: log: (pid 982) 448641s
run: rabbitmq: (pid 3755) 448561s; run: log: (pid 974) 448641s`

Comment: lsof comes in ubuntu and nginx is not being used.

Comment: Can you also add the output of `chef-server-ctl tail`. That shows any errors chef has

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot for this issue. I did lot of google search. Finally I got 1 solution.

**RabbitMQ service runs on `5672` port.** But this port is used by some other service. So I run to check is any services running on `5672` port using following command:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 5672
```

I killed service having port 5672 using following command :

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:5672`
```

Then I run the `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` again and it worked as expected.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer multiple times. Instead, when applicable, leave a comment pointing to your answer at another question. Also, look at the accepted answer to a **much** better way to handle this.